# How can I do an INSERT INTO from 3 different tables?

Tags: sql, join, insert

My goal is to fill this table with data:

**Table_1**

```
ID_coordinates, ID_text, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7
```

`ID_coordinates` is from **Table_2**:

```
ID_coordinates, latitude, longitude
```

`ID_text` is from **Table_3**

```
ID_text, income
```

`column3, column4, column5, column6, column7` are from **Table_origin**: this table also has columns `latitude`, `longitude` and `income`.

Do I need 3 different insert into statements with select or one insert into statement with joins?

Many thanks for all tips and answers.

Comment: Your latter option is the correct one. Write your query to select the data you want then simply use as the source for the insert.

Answer (score 0):

One statement with Joins (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).

If I have followed all the columns on the tables correctly it should be something along these lines:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_1 (ID_coordinates, ID_text, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7)
SELECT t2.ID_coordinates, t3.ID_text, o.column3, o.column4, o.column5, o.column6, o.column7
FROM table_origin o, table_2 t2, table_3 t3 
WHERE o.latitude = t2.latitude
AND o.longitude = t2.longitude
AND o.income = t3.income
```